# Expo AV Audio Recording with Youtube Video In Background Audio Balance Issue - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-webview, expo-av

I've got a really unique use case that I've been struggling with. I've been using Audio expo-av and a react-native-youtube-iframe or webview to play a video and record audio at the same time. You are probably all thinking... why would someone need this, but I have a really unique use case for narrating over a video. I've tried all the different configurations of the expo audio player (see commented lines 21, 22, 23 in expo snack).

If I use 'InterruptionModeIOS.DoNotMix', the videos play full volume but then if you pay attention to the console.log, the audio stops capturing (durationMillis) get 0'ed out as soon as the video plays.

If I use 'InterruptionModeIOS.MixWithOthers', the videos play and the microphone records but some of them have the volume reduced so low that you cannot hear them at all.

You'll notice that the expo-av 'Video' example in the expo snack is still loud enough to hear, but the random reddit video played in the web view is fairly dim. These are just some examples.

I'm looking to figure out how to balance these two better (or not at all). I would like the microphone to function completely normal, but set the video volume manually w/ code (say 50% for instance). I don't want the audio player to take control.

Essentially I'm looking for an 'InterruptionMode.NonExistent' so that both the video plays in full volume and the microphone records at full capacity. I do understand that this will lead to some audio distortion, but I believe I can manage that with volume settings, etc.

See expo-snack here:
https://snack.expo.dev/@christophergabba/audio-balance-example

Thank you so much in advance for your help!